# Change url link language in web site

Tags: javascript, xml, url

I have a website with 4 languages

My doubt is if I can use XML in my php

Example:

-FROM mysite.com/es/ to mysite.com/en/ mysite.com/de/ mysite.com/ru/

-FROM mysite.com/es/categoria/ to mysite.com/en/category/ to mysite.com/de/kategorie/ to mysite.com/fr/categorie/

And vice versa

Only javascript?

javascript with xml (links into xml)??

Thanks

Comment: Why do you doubt?

Comment: Can you add some details ? I don't understand your question.

Answer (score -1):

When I´am for example in "contact" (spanish), if i do click in "English", go to contact in English. And vice versa too.  But I need a website in 4 languages, and my script is for two languages. And muy doubt is if I can create and xml file, or a large javascritp.

My code

```
var seccion = $('body').data('seccion');
seccion = ("#".seccion);
$(seccion).addClass("active");

// Change lenguagea
var urlactual = window.location.pathname;
var lngurl = urlactual.split("/");

// alert(lngurl[3]);

switch (lngurl[1]) {
    case "es":
        switch (lngurl[2]) {
            case "coches":
                switch (lngurl[3]) {
                    case "/es/coche/coche1/":
                        var changeurl = "/en/car/car1/";
                    break;
                    case "/es/coche/coche2.html":
                        var changeurl = "/en/car/car2/";
                    break;
                    default:
                        var changeurl = "/en";
                }
            break;
            case "bicis":
                var changeurl = "/en/bikes/";
            break;
            case "contacto":
                var changeurl = "/en/contact/";
            break;
        }
        break;
    case "en":
        switch (lngurl[2]) {
            case "car":
                switch (lngurl[3]) {
                    case "/en/car/car1/":
                        var changeurl = "/es/coche/coche1/";
                    break;
                    case "/en/car/car2/":
                        var changeurl = "/es/coche/coche2/";
                    break;
                    default:
                        var changeurl = "/es";
                }
            break;
            case "bikes":
                var changeurl = "/es/bicis/";
            break;
            case "contact":
                var changeurl = "/es/contacto/";
            break;
        }
        break;
    break;
    default:
        var changeurl = "/";
}
//alert(Npag);
// Chnage links of footer
$(".change-lng").attr("href", changeurl);
$(".actu-lng").attr("href", urlactual);
```

Thanks